# div over flash in a lightbox

Tags: jquery, css, flash

I have created a custom lightbox that displays a flash file. The app is required to open the jQuery Datepicker above the flash file.

Here is the problem; only the header, the month name and navigation appear over the flash app. Everything else is below it.

I tried the wmode=transparent trick, but it makes the Flash app transparent and you can see below it. Plus, I believe the datepicker is having the same issue, where the month navigator is above flash, and the numbers are below the app.

lee

Answer (score 0):

Did you check all the `z-index` properties ?

With correct `z-index`, `wmode=transparent` and a `background-color` under your flash, it should be ok.